# Sequence of continuous functions which converges to a continuous limit

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Any help with this: construct a sequence of continuous functions defined on $ [0,1] $ which converges pointwise but not uniformly to a continuous limit ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f_n: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}
 nx   & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac1{n}$}\\
 2-nx & \text{if $\frac1{n} \le x \le \frac 2n$}\\
 0              & \text{if $ x \ge \frac2n $}
\end{cases}$$

It is not hard to verify that the pointwise lmit of $f_n(x)$ is 0. In fact, it is obvious that
. Now for any $x \in (0,1]$ we will have a sufficiently large N such that
$f_n(x) = 0$ if $n \geq  N$. However, $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to 0 due to the fact that $\sup|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1$ for $x\in [0,1]$

Comment: Isn't this the same as Davide Giraudo's answer?

Comment: @pete My answer is the same as LordFarin's, but maybe it isn't readily apparent, and we certainly didn't do it purposedly.

Comment: @Peter: Upon further reflection, all of the answers except Ross Millikan's are extremely close.  And in fact when I looked at the question the answer that popped into mind is in the same class as these and in fact identical to Lord Farin's.  (I like that version of the answer better because it shows that pointwise convergence is not enough to interchange the sum and the integral.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider $f_n: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}
 2n^2x   & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac1{2n}$}\\
 2n-2n^2x & \text{if $\frac1{2n} \le x \le \frac 1n$}\\
 0              & \text{if $x \ge \frac1n$}
\end{cases}$$

What is the pointwise limit of the $f_n$?

Comment: There must be some typo. $f_1(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_n$ the linear interpolation of $(0,0),(n^{-1},1),(2n^{-1},0),(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence of null functions that have a triangular jump of length $1/n$ and height $n$ on $x=1/2n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  to have it converge pointwise but not uniformly you need the function to get steeper and steeper somewhere.  A natural try would be $x^n$ which gets steeper and steeper near $1$ as $n \to \infty$.  Unfortunately, the resulting function is not continuous:  it is $0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ but $1$ for $x=1$  Can you see how to fix this?

Comment: Yes I considered that sequence but discarded because the limit is not continuous. I think maybe $ f_n(x) = x^n/n $ can work?